# How to locate the href element using selenium python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

How to locate the href elements using selenium and python

i tried below code but its not working

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
```

Comment: I think you're on the wrong track here : `href` is _not_ a DOM element ; it is a property of the  `a` element. See [the documetation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath) for practical examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To locate `href` *attribute* usually you can use

```
//a/@href
```

but `selenium` doesn't support this syntax as in `selenium` you can locate webelements only.

You can try below:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a").get_attribute('href')
```

With this line of code you should be able to get `href` attribute of the first anchor element on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code with replacing href attribute value with your value.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='href attribute value']");
```